# Create a ControlTemplate for Xamarin without using XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin, controltemplate

Without using XAML does anyone have an example where they create a ControlTemplate for an element?

Example:

```
<ControlTemplate>
      <Grid>
           <//Inner grid elements>
      </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

      
  to C# code
      

var grid = new Grid();

//This isnt how you do it Im stuck here 

var ControlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(grid)
```

Comment: Microsoft's guide to Xamarin.Forms control templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template

Comment: AFAIK, that doc doesn't show a c# code snippet to create a ControlTemplate.

Comment: How do you plan to use it? Are you sure you don't want to define a `DataTemplate` instead? See [Creating a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating) - easily defined in c#. If you really want a `ControlTemplate`, it'll be similar to that syntax. Though I've never tried, so I'm not sure about c# syntax equivalent to `TemplateBinding` markup (needed for a useful control template).

Comment: Sorry it took me  a while to circle around. Short answer here is that while i did manage to get a control template to take in my grid i created. Example new ControlTemplate(()=>grid);

Comment: I now was running into a new issue that i eventually gave up on and just when the xaml route. The issue was that my grid was using a visual state manager and i found it impossible to reference my element with just c# code within the visual state. See in xaml we are given the directive x:name which allows us to reference elements within the xaml however when using all c# that was impossible and i couldn't find any further documentation to help me address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the code below.

```
 public class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Grid1));
        ControlTemplate = controlTemplate;
    }
}
public class Grid1 : ContentView
{
    public Grid1()
    {
        Grid grid = new Grid()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition{Height =GridLength.Auto},
                new RowDefinition{Height =GridLength.Auto},
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width= GridLength.Auto},
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width= GridLength.Auto},

            },

        };
        grid.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "column0,row0",
        }, 0, 0);

        grid.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "column1,row1"
        }, 1, 1);

        Content = grid;
    }
}
```